# Why are my theorems not italic?

Tags: formatting, theorems

I am writing my thesis using [Thesis](https://github.com/wang-chen/thesis_template_ntu/blob/master/Thesis.cls) document class in latex.
However, all my theorems are not in italic font.
I am not sure where is the problem.

For your reference, the following is my preamble of my latex file.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{Thesis} % Paper size, default font size and one-sided paper

\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}
\let\savedegree\degree
\let\degree\relax
\let\savedegree\ref
\let\rem\relax

\usepackage{amscd,amssymb,verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{30}
\providecommand{\U}[1]{\protect\rule{.1in}{.1in}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{cor}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{Def}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{ex}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{question}[theorem]{Question}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,noresetcount]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib} % Use the natbib reference package - read up on this to edit the reference style; if you want text (e.g. Smith et al., 2012) for the in-text references (instead of numbers), remove 'numbers' 

\title{\ttitle} % Defines the thesis title - don't touch this

%extra packages
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{color,soul}
```

The source of this template is taken from this [github page](https://github.com/wang-chen/thesis_template_ntu/blob/master/mythesis.tex).
All necessary files can be found there.
Note that the preamble above is not exactly the same as given in the github page as I modified it to suit my purpose.

Comment: This does not compile, and the problem is in one of the files you did not provide, such as `Thesis.cls`.  One possibility is that it defined a different theorem style that applies to every new theorem you define. A less-likely possibility is that it loaded a font without italics.

Comment: If the former, adding `\theoremstyle{plain}` before the first `\newtheorem` should fix it.

Comment: If the latter, you should be getting warning messages about how some font is not available in `/m/it`, so`/m/n` was substituted.

Comment: @Davislor I have added the github link that contains all necessary files to run the template.

Comment: @Davislor Indeed, adding `\theoremstyle{plain}` before the first `\newtheorem` italizes all fonts in theorems. Thanks. Perhaps you can put it as an answer below so that I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 2):

Your example doesn’t compile, and the problem was in one of the files you include but didn’t share.  That unfortunately makes it impossible to test possible solutions.  It would be easier to help you if you provided a MCVE (and removing extraneous lines until you’re left with the minimal set of commands that reproduces your problem is a good way to narrow it down).

However, a follow-up question showed that your `Thesis.cls` defines a new theorem style.  Since that was the most recently-defined theorem style, it applies to every new type of theorem you create.

You can reset the theorem formatting by putting the command `\theoremstyle{plain}` before the first `\newtheorem`.